# Struggling with Jquery Accordions

Tags: jquery

I have a series of accordion tabs with the following markup.

```
   <h3 class="formTitle"> Miscellaneous Forms</h3>
    <div class="misc formwrapper" style="display: block;"> 
      <ul>
          <li>Item
             </li>

        </ul>
     </div>
  <h3 class="formTitle"> Miscellaneous Forms</h3>
    <div class="misc formwrapper" style="display: block;"> 
      <ul>
          <li>Item
             </li>

        </ul>
     </div>
  <h3 class="formTitle"> Miscellaneous Forms</h3>
    <div class="misc formwrapper" style="display: block;"> 
      <ul>
          <li>Item
             </li>

        </ul>
     </div>
```

Each H3 acts as an according that is used to trigger a reveal with the following JS.

```
$( ".formTitle" ).click(function() {
    var item =$(this).next(".formwrapper").toggle("medium");
});
```

This works to toggle the items just fine, but am wondering how to hide OTHER tabs that might be open. Say I click on ONE then two, how do I hide one back?

I've tried Siblings and not(($this)) but I can't quite get the logic right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

```
$(".formwrapper").not($(this).next(".formwrapper")).hide();
```

Comment: Perefect, I tried something similar but  think I got the not this structure wrong, THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

here is a piece of logic ;)

```
var allPanels = $('.formTitle').children().hide();

      $('.formTitle').click(function() {
        allPanels.slideUp();
        $(this).children().slideDown();
        return false;
      });
```

Comment: thanks Mat, just out of curiousity, why put it in a variable?